# Invertibility of $A^TA$

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to show that when having an $m\times n$ matrix where $n > m$ (more columns than rows), then $A^TA$ is not invertible, so I have set it up as follows:

$A = \begin{bmatrix}a&b&2a\\c&d&2c\\\end{bmatrix}$

Then: $A^TA$ is:

$ \begin{bmatrix}a&c\\b&d\\2a&2c\end{bmatrix} *\begin{bmatrix}a&b&2a\\c&d&2c\\\end{bmatrix}$

The resultant matrix is a 3x3 matrix with a bunch of letter terms. How can I show that this matrix is not invertible? I tried to calculate the determinant however it gets super messy?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

$rank(A^TA) \leq m < n$, hence it is not invertible.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the vector $v = (2, 0, -1)^T $. Then, we have $ Av = 0 $ and so $ (A^T A) v = 0$, so $ A^T A $ has nontrivial nullspace and cannot be invertible.

Answer (score 0):

As there are already nice answers why $A^T A$ is not invertible, let me give an answer which is more about who to compute such a determinant. There is a formula which is due to Cauchy and Binet, which reads for $A\in Mat(m\times n), B\in Mat(m\times n)$

$$ det(AB) = \sum_{S\in \binom{[n]}{m}} det(A_{[m],S}) \cdot det(B_{S,[m]}),$$

where

$$\binom{[n]}{m}=\{ S \subseteq \{1, \dots, n \} : \vert S \vert = m \}$$

and

$$ A_{[m],S} = (A_{i,j})_{1\leq i \leq m, \ j\in S}, \quad B_{S,[m]} = (B_{i,j})_{i\in S, \ 1\leq j \leq m}.$$

From this one would get as well your claim, as $\binom{[n]}{m}=\emptyset$ for $m>n$.